# Mashape in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c

i've found an api that i would like to use in my IOS app. The thing is that i'm not sure to use it exactly. i've searched around the web and have not found anything useful. The api is a login api.

https://www.mashape.com/alikonda/league-of-legends-tribunal#!endpoint-User-Login

in my app i have 2 UITextfields (username and password) after this it should use the API to check if the password and username combination exists trough the API. How can i obtain this?

Comment: In the API documentation click on "Objective-C" above to see sample code. You need to use the captcha and login endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API you're talking about is a REST API.

If you know how to interact with RESTful APIs, then you can use **NSURLConnection** to send requests.

If you feel adventurous, you can also use a 3rd party library, like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).